# jQuery - scroll div with overflow-y: scroll;

Tags: jquery, css, usability

I have a div that contains a list of messages (it's a chatroom application). As each message is added to the bottom of the list, I *think* I want the div to be scrolled to the bottom of the page. That make sense, right? So - questions #1: how do I get the div to scroll to the bottom?

Now, the next question is a bit about usability. What if the user scrolls up to read something that was previously posted? Then suddenly someone posts a new message? That means the jQuery will scroll down again. This can be very irritating to the user. What's a good way to handle this? Should it only scroll down if the scroll bar is scrolled all the way down already before a new message is added? If so, how to do that in jQuery? Or is there a more usable solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the position of the scrollbar by `window.pageYOffset` and then use `window.scrollTo(0, y)` to scroll to some place.

or you can even use `$('#mydiv').scrollTop(newmsg_top)` in jquery to scroll down to the new message.

where `var newmsg_top = parseInt($('#mydiv li:last').offset().top);`

here `#mydiv` is the div with all your messages.
  so `#mydiv li:last` points to the last message.
`offset()` returns the current position of the element with respect to the document and you can get the top position by `.top`

If you want the relative position with respect to the parent instead you can go with `position()`

**EDIT :** ***Got a jsfiddle working here [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sunu0000/K32uD/4/). Please take a look.***
Note : You go down only if you are viewing the last element.(for the solution of your usability issue)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what "top offset of new message" is or how to get it.

Comment: i have edited a bit , see if you can get it to work .. or else i will try to type in the whole block of code :)

Comment: OK, I got how to use `scrollTop`. What about the usability problem? Don't you think it'll be annoying if it keeps scrolling to the bottom when you scrolled up to read something?

Comment: you should check for the Y-offset of the window with window.pageYOffset , if it is equal to the y-offset of your current last message then the user is at the bottom and you can go ahead and scroll down

Comment: How does `window` know it's referring to the containing div of the messages? And instead of doing this myself - is there a plugin for this?

Comment: well i don't really know of any plugins. You see i'm kinda new too. Anyways let me build you a jsfiddle for this , so you get what i am talking about.

Comment: added a jsfiddle ..please have a look

Comment: well it works fine for me.. note that you go down ONLY IF you are viewing the last element (as you need in your project)

Comment: well if you are at the top and you click the button nothing happens ...but you are at the last list element and you click the button it scrolls the page all the way down .... that is the functionality you want, no?

Answer (score 2):

// this is will scroll to the end, after    append

```
$("#mydiv").append("My data");
var newmsg_top = parseInt($('#mydiv')[0].scrollHeight );
$('#mydiv').scrollTop(newmsg_top);
```